# how to decode the json ajax response

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i am having trouble with decoding the ajax reponse ,here i am sending the organisation,location and building as the inputs which in return gives 2 keys as entrance/exit and key ,now my ajax call is working fine and i can alert the response ,now my reqiurement is to decode the json array i have got and then take the value of entrance/exit into a form field called entrance/exit in the form and type into type field in the form .I have tried to decode the json in the php phage which is executed when the ajax is called and stored the 2 values into sessions but it was not showing up in the form fields when i give the value =$_SESSIN[type] and $_SESSION[entrance/exit] after that i have tried to decode the json script with javascript using console can any one figure out what i a doing wrong.
the code upto this is

```
 //ajax
 function ajax()
{
var org=document.getElementById('category_id').value;
alert(org);
var loc=document.getElementById('category_id1').value;
alert(loc);
var bui=document.getElementById('category_id2').value;   
alert(bui);
var req;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   req=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
   req=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
req.open("POST", "ajax.php?&org="+org+"&loc="+loc+"&bui="+bui+"", true);
req.send();
req.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if(req.readyState==4&&req.status==200){
       //$(".error").hide();
       result=req.responseText
       alert(result);
       var strJSON = 'result';
       var objJSON = eval("(function(){return " + strJSON + ";})()");
       alert(objJSON.name);
       alert(objJSON.type);

       }
   }
}
 <form name="theForm" method="post" action="addmachine.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate();">
      <label for="orgname">Organisation Name</label>
                <select style="width: 305px;text-align:left ;"  name="category_id" id="category_id" onchange="OrganisationName(this);">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                 <option value="1">1</option>
                 <option value="2">2</option>
                                  </select>

                <p>
    <label name="location">Location</label>

                 <select style="width: 305px;" name="category_id1" id="category_id1" onchange="LocationName(this);" >
                 <option value="">Select</option>
                 <option value="1">1</option>
                 <option value="2">2</option>

                 </select>
                </p>
                <p>
    <label for="building">Building</label>

                <select style="width: 305px" name="category_id2" id="category_id2" onchange="BuildingName(this);" onchange="ajax(this);">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
                </p>
                <label for="entr/exi">Entrance/Exit</label>
                <input type="text" name="ent" id="ent" value="objJSON.name" placeholder="enter entrance/exit"/>
                <p>
                <label for="type">Type</label>
                <input type="text" name="type" value="objJSON.type" placeholder="enter your work station"/>

      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="workstnname" name="workstnname" placeholder="enter your work station" onblur="return name();" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);">
      <label for="description">Description</label>
      <textarea name="description" style="height:150px;width:300px;"></textarea>
      <label for="machinetype">Machine Type</label>
                <select style="width: 305px;text-align:left;"  name="machinetype">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="kiosk">kiosk</option>
                <option value="workstation">workstation</option>

              </select>
                <p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                </p>

    </form>
  </div>
```

i am not getting the value of the keys entance or exit and type 
the json iam getting in response and is alerted is

```
[{"name":"Default Entrance + Exit","type":"both"}]
```

i dont know whether i have did some bluders in the code or not,as i have only started with javascript
thank you

Comment: @ArunKillu post the answer as answer....:)

Comment: Iam getting the responses [object,object]. I would like to print the value Default Entrance + Exit and both

Comment: Please make sure your ajax.php is returning correctly.

Comment: I believe your alerts will work if you do `alert(objJSON[0].name);` You should be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the security and workflow reasons it's better to parse json by **JSON.parse**

```
var objJSON = JSON.parse(strJSON);
```

not by **eval**

Comment: Thank you.. Worked like a charm.. Now How can I take the value into my form field for entrance / exit and for type field in the form

Comment: As i understand you are not using jQuery or any other JS library... Which browsers needs to be supported? Which field need to be filled with data?

Comment: Mozilla , chrome and Safari are the browsers I want to be supported. In the form , below the ajax call .There is a field called Entrance/Exit which should be filled with default entrance/exit and there is another field called type, which suppose to be filled with the value=both.     Thank you Sir

Comment: _document.getElementById('ent').value = objJSON.name;_
_document.getElementById('type').value = objJSON.type;_ |

// you should add id="type" to your type input tag in order to get element by this method, but it works in almost all browsers. those lines should  be executed on ajax response, f.e. instead of your alerts

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
  var objJSON = JSON.parse(result);
  alert(objJSON.name);
  alert(objJSON.type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("interests");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
        list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("interestKey"));
    }
```

using  [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/) library